# How to calculate the accuracy score from out of sample data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

for example -

```
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

from sklearn.nighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

knn = KNeighborsClassifier()

knn.fit(X,y)

pred = knn.predict([3,5,4,2])

print(pred)
```

output: [2] ... here 2 represents a class value
How can I calculate the accuracy of this prediction?

Comment: Please indent the question correctly. Code and text should be seperate

Comment: You seem to be interested in a *confidence* rather an accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant probability instead of accuracy since you cannot calculate accuracy at single point.

Instead of

```
pred = knn.predict([3,5,4,2])
```

use

```
pred = knn.predict_proba([3,5,4,2])
```

It should give you probability of data point belonging to class.

If you are looking for overall model accuracy, you can do cross validation.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import cross_val_score
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
scores = cross_val_score(knn, X, y, cv=10)
print(score.mean())
```

Output

```
0.96666666666666679
```

Comment: It returns two values -> [[ 0.37881165  0.62118835]]
what does it mean? Is it gives two possibilites?

Comment: Yes. So the first number is probability that `[3,5,4,2]` belonging to `Class-1` is 0.38 and that to `Class-2` is 0.62. Since probability of data point belonging to Class-2 is high, the data point is predicted as Class-2

Comment: You could use either probabilities `pred[:,0]` or `pred[:,1] `  to determine accuracy of data point belonging to Class-1 or Class-2.

Comment: Thank you so much :) .. Does is classify sortedly? My class value is consequently 0 and 1

Comment: What do you mean by classify sortedly?

Comment: I meant does it classify the first class value - 0 and then 1 .. 0 and 1 are my result value.. anyway I got this :)

Comment: @RagibHasan Great. If you found my answer correct, please mark it as answered.